# Using manifest.json, inject content scripts when URL matches a single word anywhere in the URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-script

I am creating a Chrome extension for an academic resource. These academic resources are mostly placed behind the web proxies of the universities.

Using *manifest.json*, how do I inject my content script only into those websites that contain the word `'foobar'` in the URL (anywhere in the URL, either the host or the path)?

Comment: Actually, I did indeed get it working quite fast by encapsulating the content script within ```if ( window.location.href.indexOf("word") != -1) {...}``` and putting "content_scripts:" "matches" on ```<all_urls>```, but I still would prefer doing it with manifest.json because now I'm triggering the content script on every page that the user visits. Which feels a bit wrong.

Comment: _"contain the word "foobar" in the URL"_ - anywhere, in the host part, or in the path?

Comment: Yes, anywhere. Either the host part or the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you desire using the `include_globs` key within the object describing your `content_scripts` injection. It could be something like:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "include_globs": [
            "*foobar*"
        ],
        "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
]
```

In order for the content script to be injected, it must match both the criteria in `matches` and that in `include_globs` (and must not match anything in `exclude_globs`, if present).

You can not do it with only `matches`, because in `matches`, the `*`, when used in the host portion of the match, is only permitted as the first character of the host.

References:

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)
- [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)